# Is RectF.centerpoint wrong?

Tags: delphi

I do not understand something.  If I have a `TRectF` with a width of 4 pixels:

```
aRectF := TRectF.Create(TPointF.Create(0,0),4,1);
```

```
X = 0 1 2 3 4
    * * * *
```

Why does `aRectF.centerpoint.x` return 2 instead of 1.5? is it a *bug*?

With a `TRectF` of 5 pixels:

```
X = 0 1 2 3 4 5
    * * * * *
```

`aRectF.centerpoint.x` return 2.5, but it must be 2 !

Am I missing something?

Comment: Half of 4 is 2, half of 5 is 2.5. 

These are floating point coordinates.

Comment: but 2 is not the x coordinate of the center of aRrectF as you can see ? the center is 1.5

Comment: Nope. These are real coordinates. Half way between 0 and 4 is 2. You are getting confused with discrete coordinates.

Comment: i don't understand :( because if i need to draw on the canvas the point of the center of my Trectf, it's will be TpointF(1.5, 1) and not TpointF(2, 1) (else the drawing point will be not in the center) ... what is discrete coordinates ?

Comment: You note that the first RectF has a width of 4. Count the intervals between the asterisks you've drawn, you'll find it to be 3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misconception and is unlikely to be useful for other people

Answer (score 4):

The X coordinates span from 0.0 to 4.0 inclusive in the first example. The half way point is at 2.0.

For the second example they span from 0.0 to 5.0. The half way point is therefore 2.5.

Your mistake is in your belief that the right hand edge is one pixel to the left of where I have described.